# Angular5 : recover promise statut service in my component

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise, angularfire2, angular5

I lost all my hair on this point.
I use : Angular5 cli + AngularFire2

1° In my component my **function destroyUnicorn** call my **service updateUnicorn1**.

2° As i want to know if the request works, i made a **Promise** in my service updateUnicorn1.

3° I am unable to listen if the request resolve or reject omg ^^. If the request doesn't work I want to **display console.log("error") and execute another function in my component**, on the other hand **i want do display console.log("success") and execute another function** in my component.

(But console.log works in the service)

**My Component.ts :**

```
destroyUnicorn(item){
    this.itemService.updateUnicorn1( {
        statut: "destroyed",
        id: item.id
    })
    .then(function() {
         console.log('success');

    }).catch(function(something) {
         console.log('error');
    });
};
```

**My service.ts**

```
    updateUnicorn1(item) {
          let self = this;

          let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            self.itemDoc = self.afs.doc(`unicorns/${item.id}`);
            self.itemDoc.update(item)
            .then(resolve => {
                   console.log('all good');
            })
            .catch(reject => {
                  console.log('catch');
            });

        });  
       return promise;   
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my boy !

First your component is marvellous so : 
**Component.ts**

```
destroyUnicorn(item){
    this.itemService.updateUnicorn1( {
        statut: "destroyed",
        id: item.id
    })
    .then(function() {
         console.log('success');

    }).catch(function(something) {
         console.log('error');
    });
};
```

Second: the problem is the promise structure :
So let's do that:

```
updateUnicorn1(item) {
      var self = this;

      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ 
        self.itemDoc = self.afs.doc(`unicorns/${item.id}`);
        self.itemDoc.update(item)
        .then(()=>{ 
            resolve({success :true}); 
        })
        .catch((err)=>{ 
            reject(err); 
        }); 
    }); 
  }
```

I Think the problem was the return. See you